# Vuetify tooltip doesn't show

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using the example from the Vuetify documentation for the tooltip into my app, but the tooltip doesn't appear when you hover over the specified element:

```
<v-tooltip bottom>
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
        <span v-on="on">This text has a tooltip</span>
      </template>
      <span>Tooltip</span>
</v-tooltip>
```

I added `VTooltip` into the declaration of the component:

```
import { VTooltip } from 'vuetify/lib';

components: {
    VTooltip
}
```

I am using these versions of Vue and Vuetify:

```
"vue": "^2.6.10",
"vuetify": "^2.0.0-beta.0"
```

There are no errors into the browser's console. Can someone please advise what am I doing wrong? Should the syntax be different? 
Thanks!

Comment: Did you add v-tooltip component to your project?

Comment: @NaN - Yes, I updated also my question. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Add the following imports to your `main.js` file inside the `src` folder

```
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.css'
Vue.use(Vuetify)
```

Hope this will solve your issue

Comment: import { VTooltip } from 'vuetify/lib'; // imports seems to be Ok.